# References to long scripts, and link rot

Tags: discussion

In [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1677/339) a script has been referenced. Its reasonably long, it is also versioned.

Normally, where a page is linked, its nice to also include a synopsys in the answer body, so that, if the link rots, the question still has the basic information required.

In the case of scripts though, a short version isn't much use. Should the whole script be pasted into the answer?

The other issue with pasting a whole script would be that it wouldn't track any fixes/enhancements made on the source page.

What's the preferred way of dealing with this?

Comment: It would be great if there was a website that you could feed a URL into, it would give you ond back that would redirect to the page if it is up, otherwise redirecting you to a copy kept on that website's servers. It might poll the site every few hours, if it had changed update the copy, if it 404s, set copy display to true.

Answer (score 6):

From my experience on the other Stack Exchange sites, so long as the lengthy script/program is fit to be an answer to the question, there is no problem.  This is assuming that the material in question is copied in a manner aligned with what the original author intended (and is used as per the author's copyright).

The length of the text is irrelevant, because the code is wrapped by a scroll-bar (after a minimum height is met), to ensure the styling of the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange site is maintained.

[image]

Again, I think **there would only be a problem if** code blocks were *not* wrapped, or if the user was copying material without the author's permission, or against his/her terms of use.

Comment: @Good point about the scrolling - as long as its all one block that'll keep it short enough.

Comment: Only problem is still the versioning issue. Is that just something we should put up with?